# Is it true that Donald Trump owns strip clubs?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

One of the primary things people consider in their vote is someone's character. Donald Trump is asking for a vote this season, and people commonly cite[(1)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/why-so-many-evangelicals-have-faith-in-donald-trump/2016/01/18/636ce386-bdfd-11e5-83d4-42e3bceea902_story.html)[(2)](http://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2016/january-web-only/why-donald-trump-threatens-to-trump-gospel.html) his ownership of strip clubs as indicative of his poor moral judgement.

Which strip clubs does he own? He wants his name removed from the Atlantic City casinos, so perhaps he doesn't endorse their behavior or have a direct say in their operations. Does he own or has he ever owned any directly?

Comment: Can you cite examples of people claiming that he owns strip clubs?

Comment: (Oops - I thought I was on skeptics.SE where it's mandatory to do this, but it probably won't hurt to do so here either)

Comment: Added two major sources, Washington Post, and Christianity Today. There are several non major blogs, and memes as well

Comment: For what it's worth, the Trump Taj Mahal *did* open a strip club in 2013, but Trump himself is [no longer associated with it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_Entertainment_Resorts) (aside from the use of his name) and I think he wasn't at the time.  Doesn't mean he does or doesn't own other strip clubs.

Comment: FWIW, he wants his name off of Atlantic City casinos because they hemmorage money.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it matters. There comes a point when you have enough fingers in enough pies that you can't say what a lot of them are. He might not know what all his holdings are.

Comment: @bobson and blip Isn't that some form of misrepresentation by the clubs/casinos - or did he license the use of his name as an endorsment?

Comment: @PhilLello - The latter, mostly.  The wikipedia article I linked to covers it pretty well.  He originally owned them, founded Trump Hotels and Casino Resorts (aka Trump Entertainment) and gave the new company ownership of them, and has gradually had less and less to do with THCR.  After their 2009 bankruptcy reorganization, `[Trump] signed an agreement with [an investment firm] in which he would receive 5% stock in the reorganized company and another 5% in exchange for the use of his name and likeness in perpetuity`.

Comment: @bobson Sounds like he doesn't have a leg to stand on - he agreed to remain associated `in perpetuity`, not `until no longer politically convenient`.

Comment: @PhilLello - `In early August 2014, Donald Trump filed a lawsuit demanding removal of his name from the company's two casinos, because they had allegedly been allowed to fall into disrepair, in breach of the licensing agreement for Trump's name.`  It's possible he was considering an election bid back then, but it's unlikely to be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_Entertainment_Resorts), the answer is technically no, due to the bankrupcy of Trump Entertainment Resorts in September 2014, and he may have been aware of Trump Entertainment Resorts activities in opening the strip club in 2013.

However, he has remained associated in as much as he agreed to use of his name and likeness `in perpetuity`, not `until no longer politically convenient`.

Whilst poor *moral* judgement is debatable, the licensing could be interpreted as poor judgement in general.

Comment: His Casino in Las Vegas hosts at least 2 topless reviews and a gogo club which employs dancers barely covered genitalia and pasty covered nipples.

Comment: So...still no.  And not technically no, but ACTUALLY no.  If you post an answer, post an authoritative answer.

Comment: It definitely seems like a technically no to me.

Comment: @SoylentGray  I require a complete set of pictures so I can determine how outraged I should be.

Comment: @userLTK - The only true way to understand the depravity involved is in person.